# Destroy function not working in chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, destroy

I have an application like whenever a csv data is dragged to a graph tab, it first checks whether a canvas is blank. If it is blank, it will enter if loop and create a graph for single dataset. If the canvas is not blank, it will enter else loop and create two graphs for datasets inside dialog extend box.

```
$("#graph_container").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        HoldOn.open();
        //alert(ui.draggable.text());
        // $("#info").html("dropped!");
        canvas_graph = document.getElementById('canvas');
        if (canvas_graph.toDataURL() !== document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()) {
            ...create graph
            for single dataset
        } else {
            ......create graph
            for two datasets
        }
    }
});
```

When a dialog extend box's close function is clicked i had wrote a function to destroy the graph as

```
$("#graph_container")
    .dialog("open")
    .dialog({
        height: height,
        width: width,
        title: data1 + " " + "(1990 January to 2008 December)",
        resizable: true,
        responsive: true,
        close: function(ev, ui) {
            alert("close");
            graph_myLine.destroy();
        }
    });
```

And again after closing the dialog extend box, now if i drag a data to graph tab, it is entering the else loop and creating graph for two datasets. Why the destroy function is not working here when close button is clicked?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I am new to fiddle. Here is my link https://jsfiddle.net/3dt5vevm/1/#&togetherjs=0960aAguRx. I could not make fiddle as expected.